# How to delete second and etc. symbols in string in Python?

Tags: python, replace

Example. I have this sentence: "Hello__my_beautiful___friends!"
I want this: "Hello_my_beautiful_friends!"
How can i do this? How to delete 2 or more symbol "_" in string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `re.sub`:

```py
In [5]: re.sub('_+', '_', s)
Out[5]: 'Hello_my_beautiful_friends!'
```

This uses `re.sub(patter, replacement, string)` where `_+` indicates one ore more `_` and to replace it with a single underscore.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But i get "&amp" instead of deleted "_"

Comment: "Hello_&amp" i get this, i didn't insert whole string

Answer (score 0):

In this way

```
my_string = "Hello__my_beautiful___friends!"
while "__" in my_string:
   my_string = my_string.replace("__","_")
```

Notice that the loop is needed since you may have consecutive "__" to remove and you do that with multiple iterations

Comment: You don't need a loop; `replace` will make multiple replacements. It takes an optional 3rd argument to limit the number of replacements.

Comment: @chepner You do if there are three or more underscores in a row.

Comment: There are much better ways of dealing with that.

Comment: Agreed. Doing multiple passes is suboptimal.